# django-tables2 doesn't sort columns properly

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

In the project, I have used `RequestConfig(request).configure(table)` to apply sorting across the columns. All of them are defined as `ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), null= True)` . The problem is that the title and year can be sorted, but the other three cannot be sorted properly. I get larger values among the smaller ones. I suppose the Title and Year are strings, but the others are lists containing integers. Can some one have a lead on how to properly sort the three columns in the middle ?[Table Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOQ7u.png)

[Second column not sorted properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SAr3.png)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the result of sorting integers that are stored as strings. You have pointed out that the columns of your table are defined using a `CharField` model, which [according to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField), is for storing strings.

You should probably define each of the `CoAuthors`, `Citations`, and `Ncitations` columns using [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#integerfield).

Comment: I tried that earlier, it still wasn't able to solve the problem.

Comment: How are the values of the `CoAuthors`, `Citations`, and `Ncitations` columns stored in the source database? is there a chance they stored as strings there?

Comment: No, they are stored as a list of integer values.

Comment: Hm, then perhaps the problem is that your model is attempting to sort list objects instead of the underlying integers. Is it possible to store the values as plain integers, instead of a list of integers? It seems that your table has a single integer for each column anyway.